# running asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a server 2003 dc running IIs. I want to bypass using my IIs server when accessing external websitees that I do not host, such as http://www.haifa.muni.il/haifa/Pages/homepage.aspx.

As of know, when I access the site, it takes a few mininutes to load every time.  On another server running server 2008 that is a diffrent domain, and does not have the IIs role, the site loads quickly.  I can't remove the iis role on the 2003 server, because it is being used by others.

Any help is appreciated

It seems that the external site is useing IIs, since if I change the IIS asp.net exstension to prohibit on the server.  The external site does not work.

Answer (score 0):

IIS server is not used when accessing external sites. IIS is not a proxy server. The problem lies elsewhere.

You could try checking the Network tab in Internet Explorer Developer Tools - that would show what takes up the time.